# how can ı add tls 1.3 version in java android studio project

Tags: java, android, ssl

My Android studio project language is Java . I want add TLS 1.3 Version this project. I'm using     implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2' libraries.

how can I do that ? Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade to at least OkHttp 3.12, as [that is where they added TLS v1.3 support](https://square.github.io/okhttp/security/tls_configuration_history/#okhttp-312). There may also be limitations imposed by the OS version — be sure to test TLS v1.3 on all OS levels that you support.

Comment: OkHttp 3.12 library not supported . OkHttp max version is 2.7.0

Comment: @star.java: "OkHttp 3.12 library not supported" -- you are welcome to use something newer if you choose. "OkHttp max version is 2.7.0" -- no, the latest release version right now is 4.10.0.

Comment: 4.10.0 on the okhttp3 . Okhttp3 library not supported java project. It's only supported kotlin project.

Comment: @star.java: OkHttp supports Java, at least through 4.10.0. This is covered in [their documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). [Here is a sample Java project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/master/Weather) that uses OkHttp (by way of Retrofit),

Comment: Thank you so much for support , I will review the documents, if it works, I will write it here